# Pandas reshaping

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reshape a Pandas dataframe to have a new multi-index based on a combination of some of the original columns, and at the same time unstack some of the rows. But I don't know how even after reading the tutorial on [stacking and pivoting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html).

Basically, I have:

```
# fruit      year, variable, value
fruits = \ 
 [('apples' , 2014, 'weight', 1.4),
 ('apples' , 2015, 'weight', 1.5),
 ('bananas', 2014, 'yield', 0.5),
 ('bananas', 2015, 'yield', 0.6),
 ('bananas', 2014, 'weight', 1.4)]
df = DataFrame(fruits)
```

The result should be:

```
 multi-index
/----------\
fruit   year   weight yield
apples  2014   1.4    NaN
        2015   1.5    NaN
bananas 2014   1.4    0.5
        2015   NaN    0.6
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original dataframe has a column with values `weight` or `yield`. We want these to be
column names (aka "column level values").

`set_index` can move column values into index level values.
`unstack` can move index level values into column level values.

Put the two together and we get:

```
fruits = \ 
 [('apples' , 2014, 'weight', 1.4),
 ('apples' , 2015, 'weight', 1.5),
 ('bananas', 2014, 'yield', 0.5),
 ('bananas', 2015, 'yield', 0.6),
 ('bananas', 2014, 'weight', 1.4)]
df = pd.DataFrame(fruits, columns='fruit year col val'.split())
df = df.set_index(['fruit', 'year', 'col'])
df = df.unstack(level='col')
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

which yields

```
col           weight  yield
fruit   year               
apples  2014     1.4    NaN
        2015     1.5    NaN
bananas 2014     1.4    0.5
        2015     NaN    0.6
```

---

Another option is to use `pivot_table`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['fruit', 'year'], columns='col')
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Comment: Your explanation cleared things up a lot for me, thank you. And it works.

Answer (score 1):

First create the `DataFrame` using the list `fruits` and label the columns accordingly:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(fruits, columns=['fruit', 'year', 'var', 'val'])
>>> df
     fruit  year     var  val
0   apples  2014  weight  1.4
1   apples  2015  weight  1.5
2  bananas  2014   yield  0.5
3  bananas  2015   yield  0.6
4  bananas  2014  weight  1.4
```

Multi-index with the function `pivot_table` (nb. the order of the elements in the list `index` is important):

```
>>> df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='val', index=['fruit', 'year'], columns='var')
var           weight  yield
fruit   year               
apples  2014     1.4    NaN
        2015     1.5    NaN
bananas 2014     1.4    0.5
        2015     NaN    0.6
```

If you don't want the `'var'` then `df1.columns=['weight', 'yield']` gets rid of it:

```
>>> df1
              weight  yield
fruit   year               
apples  2014     1.4    NaN
        2015     1.5    NaN
bananas 2014     1.4    0.5
        2015     NaN    0.6
```